# Populating a database through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to populate a database for a project. I have installed Xampp and I am using phpmyadmin to access the databases through a GUI. The database is a bit large consisting of economical factor needed to evaluate economic alternatives for a given problem.
PHP code:

```
function _fp($n,$i){
return number_format((pow((1+$i),$n)),5);
}

function _pf($n,$i){
return number_format((1/_fp($n,$i)),5);
}

function _pa($n,$i){
return number_format(((pow((1+$i),$n)-1)/($i*pow((1+$i),$n))),5);
}

function _ap($n,$i){
return number_format((1/_pa($n,$i)),5);
}

function _fa($n,$i){
return number_format(((pow((1+$i),$n)-1)/$i),5);
}

function _af($n,$i){
return number_format((1/_fa($n,$i)),5);
}

function _pg($n,$i){
return number_format(((pow((1+$i),$n)-$i*$n-1)/($i*$i*pow((1+$i),$n))),5);
}

function _ag($n,$i){
return number_format((1/$i-$n/(pow((1+$i),$n)-1)),5);
}

$connection=mysql_connect("localhost","root",'');
if($connection){
$db=mysql_select_db("comp_interest_fact");
if(!$db)
    echo "Failed to select 'comp_interest_fact'.\n";
}
else
echo "Failed to connect to database.\n";

$percentage=array('0_25'=>.0025,
    '0_5'=>.005,
'0_75'=>.0075,
'1'=>.01,
'1_25'=>.0125,
'1_5'=>.015,
'2'=>.02,
'3'=>.03,
'4'=>.04,
'5'=>.05,
'6'=>.06,
'7'=>.07,
'8'=>.08,
'9'=>.09,
'10'=>.1,
'11'=>.11,
'12'=>.12,
'13'=>.13,
'14'=>.14,
'15'=>.15,
'16'=>.16,
'18'=>.18,
'20'=>.20,
'22'=>.22,
'24'=>.24,
'25'=>.25,
'30'=>.3);
reset($percentage);
while(list($key,$value)=each($percentage)){
$table="percent_$key";
for($k=1;$k<=50;$k++){
    $fp=_fp($k,$value);
    $pf=_pf($k,$value);
    $af=_af($k,$value);
    $fa=_fa($k,$value);
    $ap=_ap($k,$value);
    $pa=_pa($k,$value);
    $pg=_pg($k,$value);
    $ag=_ag($k,$value);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table         VALUES($k,".$fp.",".$pf.",".$af.",".$fa.",".$ap.",".$pa.",".$pg.",".$ag.")");
}
}
mysql_close($connection);
```

The problem with this script is that once I run it, the tables in comp_interest_fact do not have all 50 rows. Actually they should because the for loop takes 50 iterations with 50 INSERT operations. I cannot find the problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: is it giving any error? any mysql error? do you have `error reporting` on?

Comment: The indentation could be improved quite a bit here, which will make it easier for you to read. The outer `reset/while/each` construct would make more sense as a `foreach` statement - this is what it's for! Consider wrapping your SQL statement so you don't have to horizontally scroll in your editor. Lastly try to avoid `mysql` functions, since they are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Change your insert condition to:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table VALUES($k,".$fp.",".$pf.",".$af.",".$fa.",".$ap.",".$pa.",".$pg.",".$ag.")") or die(mysql_error());
```

or better yet:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table VALUES ($k, $fp, $pf, $af, $fa, $ap, $pa, $pg, $ag)") or die(mysql_error());
```

Also naming your functions as you currently have them is pretty much dooming any future developer to work on your code.

Highlighting Hanky Pankys Comment:

`In Addition to this suggestion, please also note that this code will produce 1350 INSERT operations and not 50. It will run 50 * 27 Times as per your code`

If your $k is your primary key then you will be getting overridden values on each run.  You should really have an auto inc key.

Comment: In Addition to this suggestion, please also note that this code will produce 1350 INSERT operations and not 50. It will run 50 * 27 Times as per your code

Comment: @Petrograd if I set the column represented by $k (which is primary key) to auto-increment than how does the insert statement change?

Comment: @ErvinDervishaj remove the $k,

Comment: @Petrogad removed the $k. I get an error: 'Column count doesn't match value count at row 1'.